# git issues: newly added folder in one branch of git repository is visible in other branch

Tags: git

It's possible that I'm not really understanding how git works here, but I have a **development** git branch, and then I created a new branch called **development_cached**

I switched to the **development_cached branch**, freeze rails version for my project, then I ran two commands **git add .** and **git commit**  respectively, and then switched back to the **development** branch to make some other changes to that branch.

When I ran  **ls vendor** in **development** branch, its showing rails folder what I have added and committed to **development_cached** branch.

Can anybody please explain me why is it happening like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `git reset --hard HEAD` while on `development` to reset back to the state of the latest commit in that branch (and remove any other files from the directory). Note that this will wipe any uncommitted changes.

Comment: Yes Amber, issue has been solved after running git reset --hard HEAD to my development branch.

Comment: Generally if the answer is one you're looking for, you should click the green checkmark outline next to it to mark it as Accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the contents of the `vendor` folder? Was there anything added to it that was not committed to the `development_cached` branch?

Comment: Yes Manoj, whatever changes I made in development_cached branch, I committed everything